Get the current round title (Round of 256, Round of 32, Quarter-final etc) just with round ID and total knockout slots?
I'm struggling with this function to get a knockout round name with just the current roundID (zero based) and the total knockout team slots. Here is the function:
export function getKnockoutRoundName(
  thisRoundId: number, // Zero based
  slots: number,
): string {
  const totalRounds = Math.round(Math.log(slots) / Math.log(2));
  const isLastRound = thisRoundId === totalRounds - 1;
  if (isLastRound) {
    // The final round also has a third-place playoff.
    return "Final";
  }
  
  // Doesn't work here
  const currentRoundTeams = slots / thisRoundId ??;
  return currentRoundTeams >= 16
    ? `Round ${currentRoundTeams}`
    : currentRoundTeams === 8
      ? "Quarter"
      : "Semi";
}

For example, if the knockout team slots is 256, I want to get a knockout name like (Round of 256, Round of 32) based on the current round ID.

const currentRoundTeams = slots / Math.pow(2, thisRoundId) ?

cool u can post an answer if u want
